# Why am I unable to execute my code in mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm creating a script of mysql code to create a table. However it is showing me an error

I have tried removing the '' of the table name

```
CREATE TABLE 'cert' (
'CertID' int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
'Name' Varchar (45) DEFAULT NULL,
'img' LONGLOB NOT NULL
PRIMARY KEY ('CertID')
)
ENGINE=InnoDB ;
```

**This Error gets thrown:**

> ERROR CODE:1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax

Answer (score 1):

Two things- change the single quotes to back ticks. i.e. s/'/`/
and longBlob not longGlob.

My personal preference it to put the PRIMARY KEY definition on the same line as the column definition as they then to get 'lost' on longer table definitions when not paying full attention late at night. I find it easier to read that way bur your mileage may vary.

```
CREATE TABLE `cert` ( `CertID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
```

`Name` Varchar (45) DEFAULT NULL, 
   `img` LONGBLOB NOT NULL ) ENGINE=InnoDB ;

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the single quotes `(' ')` from the column names as well when creating your table.

This should be how your table structure should look

```
CREATE TABLE cert (
    CertID int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Name Varchar (45) DEFAULT NULL,
    img LONGLOB NOT NULL
    PRIMARY KEY (CertID)
    )
    ENGINE=InnoDB ;
```